# How to import an array to the function tableViewControler

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, xcode

I am implementing a table view in tableViewController in a Swift project. I am creating two array from a json calling in viewDidLoad and everything in viewDidLoad function works great. here is my viewDidLoad function.

First the arrays and variables are like this:

```
var imageList = ["usaflag","gerflag","franceflag","jpflag","gerflag"]
    
    var titleList = ["Croatian kuna","Hungarian forint","Congolese franc","Israeli Shekel","Nigerian naira"]
    
    var descriptionList = ["HRK","HUF","CDF","ILS","NGN"]
    
    

    
    
    var myCurrency:[String] = []
    var myValues:[Double] = []
    
    var aCheckEuro:Double = 0
    
    var resultCurrency:Double = 0
    
    var activeCurrency:Double = 0
    var zeroOriginActiveCurrency:Double = 0
    var oneDestActiveCurrency:Double = 0
    
    
    
    
    var currencySelected:String = ""
    var zeroOriginCurrencySelected:String = ""
    var oneDestCurrencySelected:String = ""
```

and the viewDidLoad is here

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
       
        let url = URL(string: "http://data.fixer.io/api/latest?access_key=....")
       
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
            
            
            if (error != nil)
            {
                print("ERROR")
            }
            else
            {
               
                if let content = data
                {
                    do
                    {
                        let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject
                        
                        print(myJson)
                        
                        if let rates = myJson["rates"] as? NSDictionary
                        {
                            for (key, value) in rates
                            {
                                self.myCurrency.append((key as! String))
                                self.myValues.append((value as? Double)!)
                            }
                            print(self.myCurrency)
                            print(self.myValues)
                        }
                        
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                    }
                    
                }
                
            }
            
        }
        task.resume()
        }
```

as I said until here everything is working fine. these all are in a `tableViewController` . the problem is in this function

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
       
        
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
        
        // Configure the cell...
        
        cell.cellTitle.text = titleList[indexPath.row]
        cell.cellDescription.text = descriptionList[indexPath.row]
        
        cell.cellImageView.image = UIImage(named : imageList[indexPath.row])
      
        
        cell.currencyCount.text = myCurrency[indexPath.row] // here has fatal erroe
        
        return cell
    }
```

the last line

```
 cell.currencyCount.text = myCurrency[indexPath.row]
```

has fatal error and I do not know how to solve it.I should mention that `currencyCount` is a label.

Comment: Is it an *out-of-range* or an *unexpected-found-nil* exception? And you are strongly discouraged from using multiple arrays as data source (and `NSDictionary`, `AnyObject` and `.mutableContainers` anyway).

Comment: Can you give the exact text of the error? It can give us a clue what is going on.

Comment: Don't use NSDictionary, use [String: Double] (or [String: Any]) and do not leave the catch part empty in case you get an error, add `print(error)`

Comment: @vadian exactly index out of range. this structure is the onliyest thing come in my mind because I need the my currency data in each cell. is there any other possible way you mean?

Comment: @NikolaRistic it is out of range error snd it does not continue the running

Comment: Add a struct containing String currency and Double rate and use that in one array instead of the 2 you have now

Comment: Use a custom struct to maintain all information about **one** item. This avoids the error. The fixer.io data can be easily decoded with `Decodable`. And you should handle the `success` key to catch an error.

Comment: This probably means that your ```myCurrency``` array has less items than expected. Try somewhere ```print(myCurrency.count)``` to see how much items you have.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I am newto swift and I will think about how to do it but appreciate if you answer this question in you know the answer. thank you very much

Comment: @NikolaRistic mycurrency.count has 90 rows

Comment: @vadian I am a little confused can you answer the question if possible? thank you very much

Comment: Make sure that all your lists have the same number of items (I believe that this is the problem).

Comment: @NikolaRistic thank you Nikola I will check .

Comment: In your `tableView(cellForRowAt:)` you are getting elements from 3 arrays that are hard coded with 5 elements each so it is impossible to get an index out of range error if the array contains 90 elements as you say, more likely the `myCurrency` array is empty.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I checked it in if myCurrency.isEmpty == false but seems its not null but I am checking more . thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Will Create one Array Like This :

```
var myCurrency:[String] = []
```

your Array is Empty for First TableView Load

there for you will write this code :

```
    if myCurrency.isEmpty == false {

                cell.currencyCount.text = myCurrency[1]
            }
            else
            {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It may happen when the tableView loads and there is no data yet in myCurrency array due to the delay of the network call. It will throw an *out-of-range exception*. Also may you want to put `tableView.reloadData` right after your network call finishes. What is returning the method numberOfItems?

**Update**: There are somethings that you can do.

1. Below `self.myValues.append((value as? Double)!)` put

```
    tableView.delegate = self 
    tableView.dataSource = self
```

2. In your `cellForRowAt` add a validation to check if array is empty:

```
    if !myCurrency.isEmpty {
     cell.currencyCount.text = myCurrency[indexPath.row]
    }
```

Comment: Good call, numberOfItems is probably 5 due to the hard coded arrays but that is only my guess

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried it. but it doesnt help. I checked if mycurrency is empty and I it shows that its not. do you have any other idea how to solve it?

Comment: I updated my answer. Try out and tell me if its working